# Циклическое удаление элементов списка

Tags: java, коллекции

Задан массив `{1,2,3,4,5}`; Надо удалить элементы по циклу,  начиная с `i=1`; с шагом 2: `i=i+2`; до конце остается 3.

В оригинале задача и логика выполнения выглядит так:

- choose(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2) will proceed as follows 12345 visit 1, 2 and delete 2 to get 1*345
- 1*345 visit 3, 4 and delete 4 to get 1*3*5
- 1*3*5 visit 5, 1 and delete 1 to get 3*5
- **3*5 visit 3, 5 and delete 5 to get **3
- 3 only 3 remains so return 3

Я использовал коллекцию List так:

```
List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));

boolean b=false;
while(!b)
{
    for(int i=1; i<list.size(); i+=2)
    {
        list.remove(i);
        if (list.size()==1)
        {
            b=true;
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

Нужный мне результат я не смог получить, вместо этого выводит:

[1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 4]
[1]

Comment: Непонятно. Какие нужно удалить элементы? Каждый второй? То есть в итоге должно остаться 2,4?

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, как вы собираетесь пройти с шагом 2, чтобы осталась тройка. Объясните, пожалуйста, чтобы Вас поняли и Вам помогли.

Comment: Ну по идею надо удалить элементы шагом каждый через второй, начиная с индексом i=1; в результате должен остаться  3 как : --> [1,3,4,5] --> [1,3,5]-->[3,5]-->[3]

Comment: @Талъат а если количество четное? То есть в итоге вам нужно средний элемент вынуть а не что-то там в цикле с шагом через два исполнять, так?

Comment: Там конце цикле должен остаться либо 3, либо 4. А шаг тоже может бить  по два или три ... а количество элементов не имеет разница

Comment: @Талъат а то, что нужно удалять что-то с определенным шагом это вы там придумали или задача прям так и звучит? Если у вас есть условие задачи - можете написать? А если это вы придумали - то можете написать что у вас есть и что вы хотите получить и для чего? А то всё еще ничего непонятно

Comment: choose(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2) will proceed as follows
12345 visit 1, 2 and delete 2 to get 1*345
1*345 visit 3, 4 and delete 4 to get 1*3*5
1*3*5 visit 5, 1 and delete 1 to get **3*5
**3*5 visit 3, 5 and delete 5 to get **3**
**3** only 3 remains so return 3.    И остальные то же такого типа

Answer (score 3):

Основная проблема в том, что когда Вы удаляете элемент, индекс, на котором Вы "стоите" остаётся тем же. Соответственно, если удаляется элемент с номером 1, то массив становится [1,3,4,5], а позиция находится на тройке! Следующий прыжок переместит позицию на 5, что уже не соответствует требуемому результату.
Я думаю, идея ясна.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Уже все ОК.

Comment: @Талъат А не хотите поделиться своим решением? Написать его как ответ? Думаю кому-то может быть интересным. А кому-то и полезным. =) Я, кстати, вам два способа придумал в другом ответе)

Comment: @Талъат Пожалуйста) Однако, следуя алгоритму, который Вы добавили в описание, следует учесть один момент. Каждый вложенный цикл у Вас начинается с первого элемента, что не соответствует алгоритму. Начальную позицию нужно менять в зависимости от индекса, на котором произошёл выход из цикла. Иными словами, если i == list.size()-1 , то начальный индекс равен 1, в противном случае 0. Разумеется, это только один вариант решения.

Answer (score 1):

Тут для решения явно нужна рекурсия.

Данное решение основывается как раз на прямой логике, т.е. берем номер из листа, идем дальше (допустим шаг 2; числа 1,2,3,4,5), значит вычленив 2 надо идти 3451. Это можно добиться к примеру взяв кусок из листа с индекса вырезанного элемента до конца листа и прикрепить к нему элементы с начала листа до индекса вырезанного элемента...Вычленяем опять 2-ой элемент. Это номер 4... получаем номера, которые надо последовательно пробежать: 513....и так далее, пока не останется только один.

```
private static int defaultStep = 2;
private static int defaultIndex = defaultStep;

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
  List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
  List<Integer> result = reformatList(list, defaultIndex);

  System.out.println("result: " + result);
}


static List<Integer> reformatList(List<Integer> list, int idx) {
  //System.out.println("Size: " + list.size() + ", index: " + idx);
  int listSize = list.size();
  if (idx > listSize)
    return reformatList(list, idx - listSize);

  List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();

  if (idx == 0) {
    newList.addAll(list.subList(idx + 1, listSize));
  }

  if (idx != 0) {
    newList.addAll(list.subList(idx, listSize));
    newList.addAll(list.subList(0, idx - 1));
  }

  int newListSize = newList.size();
  if (newListSize > 1) {
    idx = (newListSize < defaultStep) ? defaultStep - newListSize : defaultStep;
    return reformatList(newList, idx);
  }

  return newList;
}
```

https://ideone.com/fs0RYg

---

**UPD**

Еще один способ, более простой и лаконичный. Безо всяких итераторов.

```
private static int defaultStep = 2;
    private static int defaultIndex = defaultStep;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
        List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

        List<Integer> result = reformatList(list, defaultIndex);
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }

    private static List<Integer> reformatList(List<Integer> list, int idx) {
        if (list.size() == 1) {
            return list;
        }

        if (idx > list.size())
            return reformatList(list, idx - list.size());

        System.out.print(list.get(idx - 1) + ", ");
        list.remove(idx - 1);

        return reformatList(list, defaultStep + idx - 1);
    }
```

https://ideone.com/3WpgqG

Answer (score 0):

Работающий код, который делает то, что вам хочется.
Нужно настроить параметры под вашу задачу.

```
public class RemoverTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16));


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));

        //Текущий индекс
        int i = 0;

        //До этого индекса (не включая его) ничего делать не нужно
        int min = 1;

        //Шаг удаления - столько элементов будет пропущено между удаляемыми элементами (исключая самый первый)
        int step = 2;

        //Первая цель на удаление
        int accum = 0;

        boolean lastProtected = false;
        Object lastProtectedObject = null;

        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            boolean protectedItem =  i < min;
            if (protectedItem) {
                Object currElem = iterator.next();
                System.out.println("Этот элемент защищен левой границей " + currElem.toString());
                i++;
                lastProtected = true;
                lastProtectedObject = currElem;
                continue;
            }

            if (lastProtected) {
                lastProtected = false;
                accum = 0;
                System.out.println("С этого элемента начнется удаление (не включая его самого) " + lastProtectedObject.toString());
            }

            Object currElem = iterator.next();

            if(step == accum) {
                System.out.println("Удаляю " + currElem.toString());
                if (!protectedItem) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
                accum = 0;
            } else {
                accum++;
            }

            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));

    }
}
```

Comment: Боюсь вы сделали не то, что хочет ТС

Comment: Спасибо вам Олег, но это не тот ответ который требовали от меня. Посмотрите мои следующие объяснение и может получится правильный  результат.

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет, я решил данную задачу используя один Array.

Логика самой задачи очень проста:

1. Если у нас длина списка нечётная то удаляем вначале через 1 и в конце первое значение
2. Если у нас длина списка чётная то удаляем только через 1
3. Повторяем до тех пор пока длина списка не станет 1, и затем выводим результат

Рассмотрим на конкретном примере :

- Вначале у нас есть: 1 2 3 4 5. Длина нечётная, значит удаляем вначале через один 2 4 и затем удаляем 1
- После первого удаления у нас остаётся: 3 5. Длина чётная, значит удаляем через один только 5
- Итого ответ: 3

Можете проверить логику с любым списком и любыми числами в списке.

Ниже сам код, он создан так, что мы задаём любую длину и он выводит какое число останется последним в мозданом списке (По желанию список можно задавать самостоятельно):

```
public class Remover {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    long n = in.nextLong();                     // Задаю длину списка

    ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>(); // Создаю пустой список

    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++){              // Заполняю его заданным
        num.add(i);                             // количеством чисел
    }

    int i = 0;                                  // Буферные переменные
    int size = 0;

    while (num.size() > 1){                     // Создаём петлю, которая повторяется
                                                // до тех пор пока длина не будет 1

        if (num.size() % 2 != 0) {              // Если длина списка Нечётная

            i = 0;
            size = num.size()/2;                // Количество элементов которые удалятся

            for (int j = 0; j < size ; j++) {   // Удаляем их через for
                num.remove(i+1);
                i++;
            }
            num.remove(0);                      // После удаляем первый

        }else if (num.size() % 2 == 0) {        // Если длина списка Чётная
            i = 0;                              // Далее тоже что и выше 
            size = num.size()/2;

            for (int j = 0; j < size ; j++) {
                num.remove(i+1);
                i++;

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(num.get(0));
   }
 }
```